# Android:: Socket communication query in which java server should respond back with some text in every button click from android client?

Tags: android

I have written a code in which my android emulator acts as a client and I have a java server. Now, when i write some text in textview and click the send button the text is written in the socket and the server reads the text and write back to the socket and my client reads the data.

I want that my server should respond to me on every button click only i.e my server should recognize which button is clicked and should respond accordingly. How could i wrap some text with the button and when that button is clicked the server should recognize it. Please help, I am new to the world of android!!!
Thanks!!

Comment: Create for your system (client-server) a common button `ids` table. Each time you send a message, send along with the button `id`. On server, check the `id` for the identification of the button. There it is. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look something like this.

[Android Client Connected with Socket Server](http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-client-connected-with-socket.html)

Comment: actually i want that the server should send message with the click of the button. My objective is that whenever a button is clicked the server will send an image file. For eg. if i create a button named "lion" and when i click on it the server will send me the image of lion. So i need a mechanism to send some value to the server on the click of the button.

Comment: So in that case you need to send static value 'Lion' to server and on server side you need to check value here "String message = in.readLine();" where message.equals("lion") then pass your required value to client(messageListener.messageReceived(message))...

Comment: how can i send this static value "lion" to the server on the click of a button in my client. I have my server code ready i just need a mechanism to send this value to the server on just a button click.

Comment: Using Android project, you can send static value from android with sendMessage("Lion") method.